# How can I lock the screen settings in android

Tags: android

Well I'm doing an application wich lock some apps for a period of time, my problem comes when the user open the screen settings and change the time (hour), I want to lock the screen settings. I searched about it but I don't found nothing to can help me. I Think that it can do it with broadcaterReceiver or services but I don't really know, help please.

Answer (score 0):

check following link for best example of broadcast receiver.

[reference link1](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

[reference link2](http://androidexample.com/BROADCAST%20RECEIVER/index.php?view=examplecloud&scat=5)

1)one broadcast receiver file create.
when date change from setting....the current date have been already stored in sharedprefernce and check this sharedpreferencedate to changable date of setting..if both are different then call broadcast receiver.and in broadcast receiver ,it will be code implement of lock screen of any application which you want...

I hope its useful to you..

Comment: But wich will be the action to know the screen settings was opened?